# Build R source code from windows

Tags: windows, r, cmd

1. C:\Work\R contains the R-3.1.1.tar.gz file
2. I have build R source(R-3.1.1) in windows 8 from the following commands

   ```
                cd  C:\Work\R
                tar --no-same-owner -xf R-3.1.1.tar.gz
                cd C:\Work\R\R-3.1.1\src\gnuwin32\
                make all recommended
   ```
3. Add the following path to the Environment variables
       C:\Work\R\R-3.1.1\bin\i386
4. Enter the R.exe in command promt
5. I got the following Error

   Fatal error unable to open the base package

System information

Windows 8, 64 bit operating System, x64 –based processor
How to resolve this error?

Comment: How to be build R is detailed in great length in the manual _R Installation and Administration_ which came with your R sources. You should start there.

Comment: i have followed the steps provided in manual R Installation and Administration

Answer (score 2):

If you are using R, you can download the newest version from [here](http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/) and then simply install it.

If you have an older version and want only to download the new one, use [those commands](http://www.r-statistics.com/2013/03/updating-r-from-r-on-windows-using-the-installr-package/) inside R:

```
# installing/loading the package:
if(!require(installr)) { 
install.packages("installr"); require(installr)} #load / install+load installr

# using the package:
updateR() # this will start the updating process of your R installation.  It will check for newer versions, and if one is available, will guide you through the decisions you'd need to make.
```

Answer (score 1):

We can resolve this issue by using the following command before build the R source code

```
Set TMPDIR=c:\cygwin64\bin
```

Here c:\cygwin64\bin is the cygwin installed location in Windows 8 machine.

Here I have mentioned the R source code build steps:

- Install cygwin setup
- Install RTools
- Create the R_HOME file in the directory like C:\R_HOME
- Place the R source code tar file in the R_HOME
- Add the following path in environment variable in first
  `c:\Rtools\bin\;c:\Rtools\gcc-4.6.3\bin;C:\cygwin64\bin\;C:\Program Files (x86)\HTML Help Workshop\;C:\R_HOME\R-3.1.1\bin\;`
- Enter the following command in the command prompt
  `Set TMPDIR=C:\cygwin64\bin`
- Set working directory as `C:\R_HOME`
- Enter the following command
  `tar --no-same-owner -xf R-3.1.1.tar.gz`
- Copy the Tcl source from `c:\R` (it will be created while installing RTools)
- Set the working directory as follow in command prompt
  `C:\R_HOME\R-3.1.1\src\gnuwin32`
- Enter the following command
  `Make all recommended`
- Enter the R.exe command in command prompt. We can enter the R terminal